# How can I hide the div without using display:none or JavaScript?

Tags: html, css

`<a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalSync">Sync</a>`
=> how to hide html tag without using display: none or js, just using pure css

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588632/how-can-i-hide-an-element-with-css-while-still-keeping-it-on-the-page

Comment: oh nice! This is also very good, tks u!

Comment: but why avoid these common techniques to hide the DIV?

Comment: @Raptor he probably doesn't want the document to change when the link disappears

Comment: @Raptor in a table row, i want to assign an extra place to open the modal, for example <a>title</a>, <p>desc</p>,..., but i am getting error when using bootstrap modal, it doesn't let me open the modal when there is no <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalSync">Sync</a> in the row, this happens when i use framework yii2

Answer (score 1):

You can hide any div using **visibility CSS** but it's stayed in same position and same same space then you need to simply use **height 0 and width 0** when you visible that's div then you can resize the height width,
Css is here, Hope it will help you

```
div{
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the z-index to negative value so it's covered up by other content.